# Dividing 1 by a power series

Tags: series-expansion

I am trying to divide 1 by a power series so that I can find the second linearly independent solution using the Frobenius method.

I would like to divide 1 by $x^2 + x^3+\frac{5}{7}x^4+\frac{7}{72}x^5$ in Mathematica and get the quotient that contains negative exponents.

Comment: You mean something like `expr = x^2 + x^3 + 5/7 x^4 + 7/72 x^5; (1/#) & /@ expr` which gives `72/(7*x^5) + 7/(5*x^4) + 1/x^3 + 1/x^2`  is this what you mean?

Comment: Like `Series[1/(x^2 + x^3 + 5 x^4/7 + 7 x^5/72), {x, ∞, 10}]`, then?

Comment: J.M. - Thanks! that works if I change $\infty$ to $0$. How do I pick your answer as the right one?

Comment: Ashish @J.M. did not post an Answer so you cannot [Accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it.  Perhaps seeing your comment he will post it as a formal answer, but I think he left a comment only because this is a fairly simple matter.

Answer (score 2):

At OP's behest: there is an even simpler way to get the required answer in this case.

```
1/(x^2 + x^3 + 5 x^4/7 + 7 x^5/72 + O[x]^10)
```